# Get number before a specified string

Tags: regex, powershell

Given the string

```
RAM Statistics: 5954 / 8174 743=InUse 746=Peak
```

I need a RegEx (or three) to extract the `743`, the `746`, and ideally the `5954 / 8174` so each can be assigned to a specific variable.

I THINK this is what LookBehind is used for, but I am having a hell of a time actually getting a RegEx to "Get the numbers between a Space and =Peak", for example.

I have tried

```
$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
$regexPeak = '(?<= )(.#)(?=\=Peak)'
$string -match $regexPeak > $null
$peak = $matches[0]
Write-Host "$peak"
```

But that's returning nothing.

UPDATE:
Per Joshua I have tried

```
$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
$regexPeak = '(\d+) / (\d+) (\d+)=\D+(\d+)=peak/gi'
$string -match $regexPeak
$peak = $matches[0]
Write-Host "$peak!"
```

And both $matches[0] and [1] return everything before the =Peak. So

```
Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746!
```

Comment: Maybe `$string | select-string -pattern '\d+(?:\s*/\s*\d+)?'  -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}` will do if you just need the numbers with an optional `/` + digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to pull apart your trial code:

```
$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
$regexPeak = '(?<= )(.#)(?=\=Peak)'
```

Your regex has a lookbehind for a space, which is OK. Then it has a middle bit with a grouping of `(.#)` and that almost certainly is not doing what you intend - a dot matches any single character, and a hash matches a hash. So it would match things like `4#`, `z#`, `##` and not `746`. Then you have a positive lookahead, which looks OK. But the combined effect is to lock the inner bit down to two characters and look for `space, two characters (where the second is a hash), equals peak`.

Probably you want `\d` to mean a digit, and `+` to mean "*match one or more times*", so `\d+`

The second thing you're doing is mixing up lookarounds and grouping. One use of regex involves matching a string like `'number is 4'` with a pattern like `'number is (\d)'`. The whole pattern matches and appears in the output, and then you query the capture groups to pick out the `4` out of the whole match. `$matches[0]` is `number is 4` and `$matches[1]` is `4`.

Another use of regex involves matching the number with a lookbehind like `(?<=number is )\d` because the lookbehind matches but it doesn't appear in the output. So the output of `$matches[0]` is just the `4` and you don't need any groups. So you're using lookarounds to match without having the text in the output, and trying to group the number as well, which works but it's overkill / unnecessary mixed use of two different approaches.

That means your regex is very close to working:

```
$regexPeak = '(?<= )(.#)(?=\=Peak)'  # change to
$regexPeak = '(?<= )\d+(?=\=Peak)'   # to indicate "one or more digits"
```

and:

```
PS C:\> $string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
PS C:\> $regexPeak = '(?<= )\d+(?=\=Peak)'
PS C:\> $string -match $regexPeak > $null
PS C:\> $peak = $matches[0]
PS C:\> $peak
746
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. With that insight I got the ratio extraction code working myself. The fact that I just needed to search for the proper format for digits was a bit of a 'Doh!' moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Pattern = '(\d+) *\/ *(\d+) +(\d+)=[^0-9]*(\d+)'
$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
if ($string -match $Pattern){$Matches[0..4]}
```

---

```
5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746
5954
8174
743
746
```

Comment: LotPings, the problem is I don't know that I can trust Peak to follow InUse, or both to follow the ration, or other values to not show up. So anything that is dependent on finding four numbers, and the first two make a ratio, the third is InUse and the fourth is Peak is going to be subject to errors. In a perfect world each value would be a line item, but Autodesk didn't do it that way, because I guess they never expected anyone to actually use the masses of data they produce.

Comment: You should include these additional restrictions in your question.

Comment: Well, I did say "Get the numbers between a Space and =Peak" in the initial post, because I expected to need that limitation. But yeah, I should have explained WHY I was being particular.

Comment: A [mcve] would include all the possible variants to match. You got some valuable responses all misled by to less information.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Regex:
`/(\d+) \/ (\d+) (\d+)=\D+(\d+)=peak/gi`

Comment: Joshua, I see that the actual text InUse and Peak isn't included in the RegEx. I suspect this might be an issue because I can't trust the formatting and content of the string. I don't control it, I am parsing someone else's file, and they have warned me of their "inconsistency". So I suspect that a single RegEx that finds just 'numbers between space and =Peak'.

Comment: Ok I'll adjust.

Comment: I made it based on what you said, let me know if that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Other method, without regex

```
$template=@"
{Data:RAM Statistics:{RamStat:   123456 /     123}       {InUseValue:743}=InUse      {PeakValue:746}=Peak}
"@

$string = 'RAM Statistics:     5954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak'
$result=$string | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template

write-host "RamStat : " $result.Data.RamStat
write-host "PeakValue : " $result.Data.PeakValue
write-host "InUseValue : " $result.Data.InUseValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer with a more complex RegEx with named groups which works on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cTSU8m/1) but fails with the script. I guess due to differences in the RegEx implementation.

```
$string = @'
RAM Statistics:     1954 /     8174       743=InUse      746=Peak
RAM Statistics:     2954 /     8174       746=Peak 
RAM Statistics:     3954 /     8174       743=InUse 
RAM Statistics:     4954 /     8174
'@

$Pattern = '(?sm)^RAM Statistics: *(?<Ram>\d+) *\/ *(?<Ratio>\d+)( *(?<InUse>\d+)=InUse)?( *(?<Peak>\d+)=Peak)?'

$string.split('`n') |ForEach{
  $_ -match $Pattern|out-null
  "RAM {0}/{1}  {2} InUse  {3} Peak" -f $Matches.Ram,$Matches.Ratio,$Matches.InUse,$Matches.Peak
}
```

---

```
RAM 1954/8174   InUse   Peak
RAM 2954/8174   InUse  746 Peak
RAM 4954/8174   InUse   Peak
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, slightly different approach here, using a RegEx object instead of the `-match` operator. Since you mentioned inconsistency I have run this twice, once with added garbage text and extra whitespace, and once with only some of the items present.

```
$MyRegEx = ([regex]'\b(?<peak>\d+)(?=\=Peak)|(?<ratio>\d+\s*\/\s*\d+)|\b(?<inuse>\d+)(?=\=InUse)')
$String='RAM Statistics: 5954 / 8174 1=somegarbage 743=InUse             746=Peak'
$Results=$MyRegex.matches($String)
Switch($Results){
    {$_.groups['ratio'].success}{"Ratio = " + $_.Groups['ratio'].value}
    {$_.groups['inuse'].success}{"InUse = " + $_.Groups['inuse'].value}
    {$_.groups['peak'].success}{"Peak = " + $_.Groups['peak'].value}
}

$String2 = 'RAM Statistics: 5954 / 8174    746=Peak'
$Results=$MyRegex.matches($String2)
Switch($Results){
    {$_.groups['ratio'].success}{"Ratio = " + $_.Groups['ratio'].value}
    {$_.groups['inuse'].success}{"InUse = " + $_.Groups['inuse'].value}
    {$_.groups['peak'].success}{"Peak = " + $_.Groups['peak'].value}
}
```

That will get you the results of:

```
Ratio = 5954 / 8174
InUse = 743
Peak = 746
```

and for the second string:

```
Ratio = 5954 / 8174
Peak = 746
```

This is accomplished by using named capture groups, and then evaluating the results looking if that capture group succeeded in the specific grouping. I accomplish that with a `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[regex]::Matches('RAM Statistics: 5954 / 8174 743=InUse 746=Peak','\D+(\d+)')|%{$_.groups[1].value}
```

It gives the next result::

```
5954
8174
743
746
```